# If $A \subset \Bbb R^n, \varepsilon>0$, then there exist a measurable $E \subset A$ such that $m^*(A-E)<\varepsilon$, show $A$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$m^*$ denotes an outer measure. 
I am trying to use the following theorem:

Let $E$ be a measurable set in $\Bbb R^n$. Then for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $G \subset \Bbb R^n$ open, $E \subset G$ such that $m(G-E)<\varepsilon$.

But the given condition is $m^*(A-E)<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is **measurable**  if
\begin{align}
m^\ast(E) = m^\ast(E\cap A) +m^\ast(E\cap A^c)
\end{align}
for **all** $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. However, by monotonicity of the outer measure, we trivially have that inequality
\begin{align}
m^\ast(E) \leq m^\ast(E\cap A)+ m^\ast(E\cap A^c).
\end{align}
Hence to show the given $A$ is measurable it suffices to show
\begin{align}
m^\ast(E)+\epsilon \geq m^\ast(E\cap A) + m^\ast(E\cap A^c)
\end{align}
for any $\epsilon>0$.

Fix $\epsilon>0$. Then by the hypothesis, there exists $F\subset A$ measurable such that $m^\ast(A-F)<\epsilon$. In particular, it follows
\begin{align}
m^\ast(E\cap A) + m^\ast(E\cap A^c) \leq&\ m^\ast(E \cap (A- F))+m^\ast(E\cap F) +m^\ast(E\cap F^c) \\
\leq&\ m^\ast(A-F)+ m^\ast(E\cap F)+m^\ast(E\cap F^c)\\
\leq&\ \epsilon + m^\ast(E).
\end{align}
where the last inequality comes from the fact that $F$ is measurable, i.e. $m^\ast(E) = m^\ast(E\cap F) + m^\ast(E\cap F^c)$.

Note: we have used the facts that $A^c\subset F^c$ and $(A-F)\cup F = A$.

Comment: I got it ! Thanks a lot 
But what if I prove like below:

Since E⊂A  , E∩Ac = Ø , E∩A=E
m*(E) = m*(E) + Ø
           = m*(E∩A) + m*(E∩Ac)
So, A is measurable
Is there any mistake?

Comment: It has to work for ALL sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Yes, E and G are sets under Rn. Isn't it?

Comment: What is $G$? Any way, in your proof you are only considering the special subsets given by the hypothesis not all subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I am sorry, I mean E and A

Answer (score 0):

Given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a measurable set $E\subset A$ such that $m^*(A-E)<\varepsilon/2$, which means there is an open set $V\supset(A-E)$ such that $m^*(V)<\varepsilon/2$. But since $E$ is measurable, we may find an open set $V'\supset E$ such that $m^*(V'-E)<\varepsilon/2$. Hence $A\subset V\cup V'$ and$m^*((V\cup V')-A)\leq m^*(V-A)+m^*(V'-A)\leq m^*(V)+m^*(V'-E)<\varepsilon$, concluding the proof.

Comment: May I ask why m∗((V∪V′)−A)<ε can prove A is measurable?

Comment: It depends on definition. An equivalent definition for measurability in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is just that "For any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an open set $V$ such that $m^*(V-A)<\varepsilon$.